# How to create an array in MATLAB using Data from an Arduino Serial Monitor?

Tags: arrays, matlab, arduino

I currently have an Omron Thermal Sensor that is running a program in Arduino to output temperatures in this format to the serial monitor:

```
ans =   
 '85.6, 85.1, 84.6, 83.5, 85.5, 84.2, 83.3, 83.1, 83.5, 83.3, 83.1, 83.5, 85.6, 82.5, 84.0, 83.8'
```

I want to use this output temperature data in MATLAB to create a 4x4 array like this:

```
Temperature Array = [85.6 85.1 84.6 83.5;
                     85.5 84.2 83.3 83.1;
                     83.5 83.3 83.1 83.5;
                     85.6 82.5 84.0 83.8]
```

I know how to open the serial monitor and read the output from the serial monitor in MATLAB (as shown below):

```
C = serial('COM9'); %#ok<SERIAL>
fopen(C);
fscanf(C)
```

This returns in MATLAB:

```
ans =    
 '85.6, 85.1, 84.6, 83.5, 85.5, 84.2, 83.3, 83.1, 83.5, 83.3, 83.1, 83.5, 85.6, 82.5, 84.0, 83.8'
```

My question is: how can I parse through or format this return so that it is displayed in this format?

```
ans = 
       [T1  T2  T3  T4;
        T5  T6  T7  T8;
        T9  T10 T11 T12;
        T13 T14 T15 T16]
```

### ****UPDATE: 7/27****

```
C = serial('COM9'); %#ok<SERIAL>
fopen(C);
L = reshape(fscanf(C,'%f, '),[4,4])
```

### Worked to output this:

```
L =

   76.6000   77.0000   76.8000   77.0000
   76.6000   76.5000   76.8000   76.5000
   76.8000   76.5000   76.6000   76.8000
   77.7000   79.3000   79.9000   77.0000
```

### How do I make this an array and add the ";" to the end of each of the Temperatures in the 4th column like this?

```
L =

   [76.6000   77.0000   76.8000   77.0000;
   76.6000   76.5000   76.8000   76.5000;
   76.8000   76.5000   76.6000   76.8000;
   77.7000   79.3000   79.9000   77.0000]
```

Comment: Use `reshape` and format specifiers for `fscanf` when you read the data.

Comment: Why -1 for this reasonable question? I am bumping this one up +1

Comment: `reshape(fscanf(C,'%f, '),4,4)` should work

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for your help. I just need to get the " [ 's " in the front and back to make it into an array.